# DNS zone and Nameserver misconfiguration

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nameserver

I can't open my site via domain name. I edited nameservers on my registrar account like this, ns1.mydomain.info x.x.x.197 and ns2.mydomain.info x.x.x.198. I set also on registrar custom nameservers as ns1.mydomain.info and ns2.mydomain.info. 
Also, my other domains that are on registrar won't let me edit DNS zones, which is OK, I can't edit DNS zone file on registrar while it's on my server. But in this case it lets me edit dns zone file, even if DNS zones are on my server.
The range of IPs that are on my dedicated server are x.x.x.194-x.x.x.198, and .194 as primary. I can open my site via http://x.x.x.194/~user/ and x.x.x.196.

My DNS config on server for mydomain.info DNS zone, (from WHM) is:

```
mydomain.info   NS      ns1.mydomain.info
mydomain.info   NS      ns2.mydomain.info
mydomain.info   A       x.x.x.197
localhost               127.0.0.1
mydomain.info   MX  0   mydomain.info
mail                    mydomain.info   
www                     mydomain.info
ftp                     mydomain.info
cpanel                  x.x.x.197
webdisk                 x.x.x.197
whm                     x.x.x.197
webmail                 x.x.x.197
default._domainkey   TXT    v=DKIM k=rsa p=...
ns1             A       x.x.x.197
ns2             A       x.x.x.198   
server          A       x.x.x.194
```

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton milenica.info

Comment: Your DNS seems to be configured mostly correctly and working fine. (Well, except for the fact that you cheated and only have one nameserver.) Exactly what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I thought I have 2 nameservers, I registered 2 of them 4-5 hours ago (maybe propagation needs more time, but before it was all fine after few hours). Exactly I'm doubting why are the DNS zones editable at my registrar, as well as is it good to set both nameservers to point to primary or dedicated IPs, and why my site can't be opened right now via domain, even if my domain is pointing at dedicated IP.

Comment: You used two different IPs, but they both point to the same physical server, which defeats the purpose of having two nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your DNS configuration is working. The webserver being pointed to does however not seem to have any content. The / URL on all the sites has just this content:

```
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></body></html>
```